# PHP move_uploaded_file - image not correct colors? (ICC Profile?)

Tags: php, image-processing, upload, color-profile, color-management

### [image: Image illustrating the problem I have]

I am trying to upload photos, but once PHP handles the upload with move_uploaded_file the colors gets all messed up and blue-ish in the color. I have no idea what all these ICC profile (designer stuff) is and all I want is to upload images that look EXACTLY like the ones the customer has in Photoshop.

I was reading about the ICC Profiles and found [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpeg-icc/)

But there are no documentation. In order for me to do this I have to have the original photo and copy the ICC profile, but before I can have the original photo I have to upload it, and in the process it ruins the ICC profile and make the image "blue" - so it's kinda like running in circles for me right now.

Does anyone have a trick for this? I prefer NON-imagemagick solutions, as I am not a fan of being dependant on third-party plugins (`server/webhotel issues everytime`).

Thanks!

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` does not alter a single byte of the file. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did not know that. I've tried to locate the error by stripping down every line of code but it still appears. I am using the [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com)  plugin to handle the upload before sending it to PHP. Is it possible that jQuery/the plugin can have an affect on it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plug-in but if it resizes or optimizes the picture, it'll certainly do. Just compare the original file with whatever PHP receives.

Comment: I've just created a default html form with simple PHP upload, and you were absolutely right. It was not the server/php, it was the plugin that somehow is messing it up, so I'm going to track that down now. Thank you for your help.

Please let me know if I can accept/upvote your answer as I do not see that option. Sorry, but I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) does not alter a single byte of the file, it's just a secure alternative to good old [rename()](http://php.net/rename) designed for file uploads and it certainly knows nothing about image formats:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename
>   is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP
>   POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

The error must be somewhere else.